# can a client intercept or spoof the http response to modify the data for its own benefit?

Tags: python, http, flask

I am developing an application that spends tokens to execute an operation.

each user has a limited amount of token and they will earn it as time goes by.

the number of tokens of each user is stored in a database as an integer, when the client application wants to execute the operation it sends an HTTP request to the server and on the server it checks the database if it has the necessary number of tokens, if the user has the necessary tokens, the server application subtracts the tokens from the database and sends an HTTP response like the following:

```
body_response:
{
    "spent_tokens": [amount]
    "can_execute": true
}
```

my question is if this is too insecure or not?, if it is possible to falsify the HTTP response?

and if it is unsure what other method I could use instead.

For the server application I am using python with flask and C# WPF  in the client application making the HTTP requests with the HTTPClient standard library

thank you for your help

Comment: If it's _http_ and not _https_ and the application is just after a `{"can_execute":true}` response then it is super easy to spoof that. It's also pretty straight forward to spoof a https response if the user is able to create a self-signed cert which your application will probably just trust if it's in the local trust store. But we are just guessing without seeing any of your code.

Comment: @LukeBriggs I have no code yet. I'm planning. about cert, is it necessary?, I have no idea about them. I'm going to deploy the server app in heroku (free plan) if it help

Comment: Your site has user authentication so yes a https certificate is a requirement (browsers will show danger warnings to your users otherwise). The "Let's Encrypt" project is commonly used to get free certificates. Your token system would however be a lot more secure if the functionality that people get tokens for runs on the servers. It's also pretty easy for an attacker to just remove the code from the application which checks the token count - if the paid functionality is on the server end then that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to spoof requests in both HTTP and HTTPS using tools such as Burp or curl. Not only is it possible, it is also extremely simple. Forging malicious HTTP/HTTPS requests is the bread and butter of any bad actor looking for flaws in your products. **You should never trust data provided by the client.** All sensitive state should be managed by a trusted server.